# How to access variable in stored proc from adodb recordset?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I'm returning a count of records from a previous select statement in my stored procedure. If I'm using this stored procedure to populate an Excel Macro via ADODB recordset, how do I access the "RecordCount" field in Excel?

Stored procedure:

```
set @EndDate = DateAdd(ss,-1,DateAdd(dd,1,@EndDate))

select
    Fields
from
    dbo.Table
where
    Field between @StartDate and @EndDate
order by
    Field desc

select @@ROWCOUNT AS 'RecordCount'
```

Returns this:

```
 Field Names
 -----------
 Data

 RecordCount
 -----------
 36
```

I want to use the RecordCount field in this line of code in VBA:

```
Dim recCount As Long
recCount = "RecordCount" Field
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need the Range property:

```
Dim recCount As Long
 recCount = Range("RecordCount").Value
```

If you need to read the value of another sheet, you would do:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
```

[see reference](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=11530)

Comment: I'm not returning this RecordCount field in an Excel cell. I want to know how I can grab this value from the stored procedure. It's being returned after the results of my select query. So I guess you can say that it's in a separate data set than my select results?

Comment: Your question was, "how do I access the "RecordCount" field in Excel?" Why would I get voted down for answering what was asked? The original post had a vba tag.